# How to get a percentage from UIImageView rotation?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, ios5

Hello I made a turnable knob but I am unsure on how to turn the rotation into a percentage 0 - 100%. Does anyone know how to do this?

Much Thanks
-Tay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you would base rotation in something like degrees? If you want to convert your degrees to a percentage... 360 / 100 = 3.6 degrees per 1%.

So example, 270 degrees / 3.6 = 75% rotation.

But what you're doing sounds a little strange.

Comment: It works fine when I use the UIRotationGestureRecognizer it returns accurate degrees from a radian but when I use https://github.com/kirbyt/KTOneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer it doesn't seem to be returning the correct radians... I need it to rotate using one finger instead of two.